# True near field distance for a short monopole antenna

Tags: rf, antenna, frequency, radio, propagation

**Antenna properties:**

- Height x Diameter = 3.3 inches x 1.4 inches
- Test Frequency: 900 MHz
  (Wavelength = 33 cm or 13 inches)

I see some conflicting formulas to calculate the near field distance for an antenna w.r.t. the frequency of interest.

**Method 1:** (multiple sources)

> **Reactive Field <= 0.63 x sqrt(Height^3/Wavelength) ===> 2.6 cm or 1.02 inches**

**Method 2:**

> **Reactive Field <= Wavelength ===> 33 cm or 13 inches**

Which one applies here accurately.

Answer (score 0):

In literature, there is a difference between the reactive near field (containing bounded energy) and radiating near field. This might explain why you have two formulas.